# How can I join three datasources with LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following:

```
var questions = questionService.Details(pk, rk);
var topics = contentService.GetTitles("0006000")
                .Where(x => x.RowKey.Substring(2, 2) != "00");
model = (
    from q in questions
    join t in topics on q.RowKey.Substring(0, 4) equals t.RowKey into topics2
    from t in topics2.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new Question.Grid {
        PartitionKey = q.PartitionKey,
        RowKey = q.RowKey,
        Topic = t == null ? "No matching topic" : t.Title,
        ...
```

Now I need to add the following:

```
var types = referenceService.Get("07");
```

Where there is a link between `questions.type` and `types.RowKey`

Is there a way that I can link this third data source and have it give a message "No matching type" if there is nothing that matches in the type table? My problem is I am just not so sure how to do the next join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can join the result of the first join with the third datasource:

```
var questions = questionService.Details(pk, rk);
var topics = contentService.GetTitles("0006000")
                .Where(x => x.RowKey.Substring(2, 2) != "00");
var  types = referenceService.Get("07");

model = (
    from q in questions
    join t in topics on q.RowKey.Substring(0, 4) equals t.RowKey into topics2
    from t in topics2.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join type in types on q.type equals type.RowKey into types2
    from type in types2.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new Question.Grid {
        PartitionKey = q.PartitionKey,
        RowKey = q.RowKey,
        Topic = t == null ? "No matching topic" : t.Title,
        Type = type == null ? "No matching type" : type.Title,
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        var questions = questionService.Details(pk, rk);
        var topics = contentService.GetTitles("0006000")
                        .Where(x => x.RowKey.Substring(2, 2) != "00");
        var types = referenceService.Get("07");
        model = (from q in questions
            join t in topics on q.RowKey.Substring(0, 4) equals t.RowKey into topics2
            from t in topics2.DefaultIfEmpty())
            select new Question.Grid {
                PartitionKey = q.PartitionKey,
                RowKey = q.RowKey,
                Topic = t == null ? "No matching topic" : t.Title,
                ...
            }).Union
            (from a in types
             join q in questions on q.type equals a.RowKey 
             where a.ID != null
             select new Question.Grid {
                    PartitionKey = q.PartitionKey,
                    RowKey = q.RowKey,
                    Topic = t == null ? "No matching topic" : t.Title,
                    ...
            })
```